# Why will my Java for loop not set the variable outside of the loop?

Tags: java, variables, for-loop, return-value

Ok so I'm working with Java and I'm thoroughly confused. I have code that looks like this

```
private double computeValue(Warehouse house) {
    double price;
    int quant;
    double value;

    for (int i=0; i < house.size(); i++) {
        price = house.getItem(i).getPrice();
        quant = house.getItem(i).getQuantity();

        value += (price*quant);
    }

    return value;
}
```

It reads through the Warehouse item for the number of times that is its size, and when it does it gets the item in the Warehouse, its price and quantity, and multiplies them together to become value

Now that's all fine and dandy, but the number that the variable value is set to WILL NOT LEAVE THE LOOP. It says that value has not been initialized when I run it, and if I set it to some random dummy number it then returns that number, as opposed to what it should get from multiplying price and quant. Can anyone tell me how to fix this so that the variable value gets a number from the loop and can return it, as well as it would be helpful to understand why it is doing whatever it is doing. Thank you!

EDIT: I fixed the problem of house.size() being 0, it is now set to be 10 and still returning the error of uninitialized value

Comment: What if `house.size()` returns `0`? What value will your `value` have then?

Comment: As in that might be the problem? It doesn't run the loop at all?

Comment: Yes, and if the loop doesn't run, your field isn't initialized. Give it a default value.

Comment: That code won't compile.

Comment: Try adding a print statement System.out.println("Entered for loop") at the beginning of your for loop. If you do not see this statement printed then house.size() equals 0.

Comment: Also, you might want to have `value += price*quant;`

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Yea....thanks for that pointer. Seems that house.size() is returning 0.0 I'll fix that and come back if its still not working

Comment: You should probably set the initial value of value like this: `double value = 0`. Also like @exception1 mentioned, your loop is just re-writing the value over and over so use `value += price*quant`. My guess is that `house.size()` might return `0` and the loop never runs.

Answer (score 3):

Could it be that your

```
house.size();
```

is returning 0?

Also are you trying to get the value of the last item in the house?

If you want to get the accumulated value of all items and their price you should probably change your value assigning to:

```
value = value + (price*quant);
```

Otherwise it will only ever return the value of the last item in the house.

Comment: Thanks for the accumulating tip, I forgot about that, however I made the house.size() now equal more than 0 (10 to be exact) and its still returning the error

Comment: @DavidGrabon try to initialize all the variables to 0 and let me know.

Answer (score 1):

Ok the answer is found, I had to set the value of double to start with a 0.0 as opposed to nothing, so now it works

```
private double computeValue(Warehouse house) {
    double price;
    int quant;
    double value = 0.0;

    for (int i=0; i < house.size(); i++) {
        price = house.getItem(i).getPrice();
        quant = house.getItem(i).getQuantity();

        value += price*quant;
    }

    return value;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the `house.size()` value possibly being `0`, either the `price` or the `quantity` values returned by `getPrice()` and `getQuantity()` probably return 0, thus causing no change to the `value` variable.

This is easy to debug. For instance, the `for` loop could include a `print` statement, as follows:

```
    for (int i=0; i < house.size(); i++) {
        price = house.getItem(i).getPrice();
        quant = house.getItem(i).getQuantity();

        value += (price*quant);

        System.out.println("\nRound #" + i + ": value = " + value + ", price = " + price + ", quant = " + quant);
    }
```

After execution is completed, the details of all the values will be available to check and verify.

Comment: Well on the price and quant variables, if they returned 0 then it still would make value equal 0 which is a value, so it would return that. Also they don't return 0 and its all working now, I put an answer it just won't let me say its an answer for 2 days or something